# Angular 2 form set selected of STATIC select menu

Tags: javascript, forms, select, angular

I've got a Angular 2 form with a static select menu

```
<select formControlName="type" name="type">
    <option value="reference">Referentie</option>
    <option value="name">Aanhef</option>
    <option value="street">Street</option>
    <option value="postcode">Postcode</option>
</select>
```

How can I set the first as the selected value. What ever I do it turns up blank.

[image]

I've tried:

```
<option selected...
<option selected="selected"...   
<option [selected]="selected"...
<option [selected]="reference"...
this.searchform.value.type = 'reference';
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.searchform.controls['type'].setValue('reference')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <option value="name" selected>Aanhef</option>
```

works. You can refer
[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8pSgivCYnHwmcQhuK1lQ?p=preview)